# Log-analytic workspace is not supporting for ubuntu 22 version

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor, azure-monitor-workbooks, azure-log-analytics-workspace

Log-Analytics Workspace going to be expire in 2024, When i tried to create alert in Azure VirtualMachine,
it shown as above 20 version Log analytics workspace is not supported.  is there any alternative for creating Alerts in Azure Virtual
machine for ubuntu 22 version by using Azure Monitor.

I'm looking for the alternatives for Log-analytics workspace, which was supported for ubuntu 22 version.

Comment: Hi, When you say "it shows as above 20 version log analytics workspace is not supported", do you mind sharing a screenshot in which step it shows such notification or message or error?

Comment: Kindly check it out below screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/agents-overview#linux) Azure document, Ubuntu 22 OS is not supported for Log Analytics agent. Recommendation is to go for Azure Monitor Agent (AMA).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIiej.png)